# How to fetch just a single build/dist file, when installing with NPM, rather than the full repo?

Tags: npm, compilation, repository, bundle, npm-install

What if one needs to just rely on a single file from a repo?

Is `package.json` supporting any way to fetch a single distributed build file, rather than downloading the whole repository?

Or should this possibility be provided by the repo's maintainer? (e.g. providing a bundle version of the repo, with just the distributed file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's up to package owner to specify particular path patterns in [`files` section](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) of `package.json`. Just like

```
"files": ["dist/*"]
```

Alongside `files` that lists *including* patterns there `.npmignore` and `.gitignore` [can be applied for exclusion](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package).

I don't believe there is anything you can control on your side.